# Changing a state of a variable in a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two fonts one if the app is in arabic and one if the app is in English. My thinking is declare the state at the top but when the user changes the font it reverts the false state.

```
const App = ({navigation}) => {
  const [newFont, setNewFont] = useState();
  i18n.on('languageChanged', () => {
    console.log('languageChanged');
    setNewFont(true);
  });

  const customTextProps = {
    style: {
      fontFamily: Fonts.GLOBAL_APP_FONT,
    },
  };
  const customTextInputProps = {
    style: {
      fontFamily: Fonts.GLOBAL_APP_FONT,
    },
  };
  setCustomText(customTextProps);
  setCustomTextInput(customTextInputProps);
  const arabictextProps = {
    style: {
      fontFamily: Fonts.GLOBAL_APP_ARABIC_FONT,
    },
  };

  if (newFont === true) {
    setCustomText(arabictextProps);
    setCustomTextInput(arabictextProps);
    console.log('fontChange', newFont);
  } else {
    console.log('fontChange', newFont);
    setCustomText(customTextProps);
    setCustomTextInput(customTextProps);
  }
```

The state is declared true when the user triggers the i18 .on function, but the app refreshes and changes the state again.

Please help me figure a way to change the state...

Comment: You need to persist the language settings in the disk and not in memory. You should use UserDefaults/SharedPreferences to do this and read the value from there to initialize the state value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const customTextProps = {
    style: {
      fontFamily: Fonts.GLOBAL_APP_FONT,
    },
  };
  const customTextInputProps = {
    style: {
      fontFamily: Fonts.GLOBAL_APP_FONT,
    },
  };
  setCustomText(customTextProps);
  setCustomTextInput(customTextInputProps);
  const arabictextProps = {
    style: {
      fontFamily: Fonts.GLOBAL_APP_ARABIC_FONT,
    },
  };

  if (i18n.language === 'ar') {
    setCustomText(arabictextProps);
    setCustomTextInput(arabictextProps);
  } else {
    setCustomText(customTextProps);
    setCustomTextInput(customTextProps);
  }
```

All I needed to do was change the if statement to check if the app is in Arabic.

Answer (score 2):

You should not change the state inside the function because it causes a loop: every time you update the state the function is called back.

Try with the below example where the state will only change when the languageChanged is called:

```
const customTextProps = {
    style: {
        fontFamily: Fonts.GLOBAL_APP_FONT
    }
}
const customTextInputProps = {
    style: {
        fontFamily: Fonts.GLOBAL_APP_FONT
    }
}

const arabictextProps = {
    style: {
        fontFamily: Fonts.GLOBAL_APP_ARABIC_FONT
    }
}

const App = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [customText, setCustomText] = useState(customTextProps)
    const [customTextInput, setCustomTextInput] = useState(customTextInputProps)

    useEffect(() => {
        i18n.on('languageChanged', () => {
            console.log('languageChanged')

            setCustomText(arabictextProps)
            setCustomTextInput(arabictextProps)
        })
    }, [])
}
```